# How to solve an error saying object delimiters is not a member of package scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical

Tags: scala, parsing, delimiter

I am writing a parser in Scala, part of the code is as follow :

```
 import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
 object ExprParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
     lexical.delimiters ++= List("+","-","*","/", "^","(",")",",")
    ...// rest of the code
 }
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 object delimiters is not a member of package scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical
```

I have checked many resources and couldn't find the source of the problem.

Comment: There is no delimiters defined in the hierarchy of the `JavaTokenParsers`. Are you looking for `object ExprParser extends StandardTokenParsers` instead ?

Comment: @AlexisC. You are right! thanks, is StandardTokenParsers a trait as well? I mean can I extend both of them?

Comment: The type of the element for a `StandardTokenParsers` is `Token` while it is a `Char` for the `JavaTokenParsers` so I don't think it will work. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's an another way to solve your problem.

Comment: I did that but I am now getting errors which I haven't had before like:" value ~ is not a member of String"  in : "def expr: Parser[Any] = terms~rep("+"~terms | "-"~terms)"

Comment: Why do you need to extends `StandardTokenParsers`?

Comment: Because like you mentioned delimiters defined in StandardTokenParsers